# Why does it never rain on my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The gamerule `doWeatherTick` is `true`.

People sleep every night. Is this preventing rain?

Comment: The great lost Travis b-side.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky. It *always* rains on my worlds... and twice as often if you use the console to set the weather to clear.

Comment: @TylerH I want powder snow :/ and also rain + riptide trident makes for amazing flight. You're the lucky one!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes.

According to the [Official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed#Passing_the_night):

> Sleeping changes the time of day to sunrise and resets the weather to clear weather.

Comment: What if the weather is already clear when you go to sleep? Does that reset the "timer"?

Comment: That is a good question, unfortunately I have no idea.

Comment: @Lolums yes the timer is reset even if it is not raining.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. The wiki says sleeping just "resets the weather to clear", it doesn't say there is any kind of "rain timer". So yes, it's always clear weather in the morning, but it still can be raining in the afternoon.

Comment: @enkryptor It has been a while, but I seem to remember the minimum rain timer is one and a half day, so sleeping every night makes rain impossible.

Comment: @enkryptor There is a rain timer in Minecraft however I'm not sure whether sleeping resets it.

Comment: @user253751 I didn't say there was no timer. I said the quoted text didn't mention it, albite it assumed it as an answer's basis.

Comment: @Jeroen The minimum rain timer is half a day - in the meaning of "day" as "20-minute day-and-night period", so the earliest rain possible would be after nightfall.

Comment: I always sleep and yet it rains in my SP world

Answer (score 20):

If an administrator previously used /weather clear 99999 it's possible that the timer is still going. You could reset it by setting the weather to rain for a few seconds and it should go back to normal.

Comment: That's an unlikely assumption to make

Comment: @RayWu How is that unlikely?

Comment: @savtoxgsc the likelihood of someone going out of their way to use `weather clear 99999` instead of either turning off the gamerule or just using `clear` on its own is small, even smaller seeing that (albeit there's none against it either) there's no indication they're on a multiplayer server

Comment: “People sleep every night” looks like sufficient indication of it being a multiplayer server, and “I think it’s unlikely to help” is hardly a solid basis for dismissing a potential solution.

Comment: We haven't been using any admin commands / cheats

Answer (score 19):

There are also some biomes where it doesn't rain - all the [dry biomes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome#Dry_biomes), even in vanilla minecraft.

I always forget Savanna counts as dry when it has grass and trees everywhere, if your base is in such a place you'd never know when it was raining elsewhere.

Comment: Doesn’t it go cloudy even in those biomes?